# How to remove double quotes from default string in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one string

```
"{'name':'xyz'}","{'name':'PQR'}"
```

I need to remove double quotes it should be

```
{'name':'xyz'},{'name':'PQR'}
```

I am able to remove double quotes but end result is always like below format

```
"{'name':'xyz'},{'name':'PQR'}"
```

i want end result should be just

```
{'name':'xyz'},{'name':'PQR'}
```

Ideas are helpful

Comment: are you trying to covert it into JSON object?

Comment: Is your JSON object in double quotes ?

Comment: I didn't have json object,it is just a string from $.post and it in double quotes

Comment: Where does the string come from? Why does it have quotes in the first place? Also, if you plan on using it as JSON then you also need to replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: @ Sverri M. Olsen string come from server side,I have needed it in above format so i didn't remove single quotes.but finally i solved by below solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is solved by converting current object to string and then used `eval` function,Worked solved thanks.

```
var eventlist = JSON.stringify(eventresult.d);//Jsonresult

var eventstring = new String();

eventstring = eventlist.toString().replace(/"/g, "");

eval(eventstring );
```

Answer (score 25):

Using below code you can remove double quotes from a string:

```
var test = "\"House\"";
alert(test);
alert(test.replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

Comment: I have done it alert also shows proper formatted string but when i tried to assign it to any attribute it shows me "{'name':'xyz'},{'name':'PQR'}" with double quotes

Comment: When you assign it to attribute then it consider as a string.

Comment: Right so is there any solution for this.?

Comment: use eval() function may be useful for you.

Comment: it only remove inside object string not remove outside object string our string is :"{"status":0,"msg":"No record found!"}"?

Answer (score 0):

Though you may resolved the issue, but question is about string you are retrieving.

its not JSON object in stringified format. You says its comes from $.post then it should not be

`{'name':'xyz'}","{'name':'PQR'}`

Its not json string representation of any JS object.

When you try to assign this one in any variable in post call it will assign only first string to varibale:

```
var a = {'name':'xyz'}","{'name':'PQR'}
```

See the result.

So first questing is is it valid string. Valid String representation of JS object could be : array of two object

```
"[{'name':'xyz'}","{'name':'PQR'}]"
```

Then just parse this string version of json object to get back JS object where

```
JSON.parse(your string representation retrieved from server)
```